# PHP session variable across multiple files

Tags: php, session

If i have several PHP files and im setting a session variable in one file, will the same set value be available in another file for same session ?

Comment: That's what sessions (over multiple requests) are for :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it should be as long as you call `session_start()` in each page

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: In each page meaning in each PHP file ?

Comment: @Cygnus no, you need to call `session_start()` once per request. The best way is to put it in your entry point (i.e. `index.php` or a `config.php` that gets included for every request). After that all files you include (during the same request) will be able to access your session variables.

Comment: It depends if you are using a framework etc. If you are using just plain PHP with no framework (and therefore no page that is included every request), you will need to include every page. The example on the PHP manual i sent explains.

Comment: @AndrewHall : I read that. Im still facing problem in my code though.
I have a GetData.php file the script in which will be executed (it sets the session variables) when page client_show.php loads. Now, im using AJAX to retrieve data from another PHP file on a user action. In that other file, i have to access the variables set by GetData.php. But when i do, the session variable is turning up as empty.

Comment: OK, there seems to be some other problem altogether. In the file in which i'm accessing the session variable ( set in another file ), it says Undefined variable $_SESSION. Any hints on what could be wrong ?

Comment: Please Edit your original post with code examples that exhibit the issue

Comment: Sorry guys. I added session_start() and there was also a typo in one line. Corrected that, and its working.
Again, sorry. And thanks everyone !! :)

Comment: OH yeah ! Had forgotten that !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will !! 
but in another file you have to call session_start(); meth0d again to access session variables

Comment: Please have a look at the discussion on Andrew Hall's answer. Any inputs would be great.